Setting the trigger on the life chat widget button
Good day.
I have a website. On which life chat is installed as a widget. I need to set a trigger on clicking the button that opens the chat. But when you click on this button, GTM does not see the click at all. How can this be implemented?
I have tried all the standard trigger setting approaches. But the problem is that GTM does not see the click on such a button. HTML buttonenter image description here
enter image description here

Can you provide some additional details? Screenshots of the variables when you click the element in debug mode? HTML of the button?

When the button is pressed, GTM does not catch any event at all

HTML added to question body above

That's an iframe and it is loaded outside of your GTM container's view. You won't be able to track any interaction.

That is, there is no possibility to set a trigger on pressing the widget button?

Not with your access. Essentially, your GTM container sees a blank space where the widget is on the screen. Unless there is something in the div above the one housing the iframe. What is within that?

You are right. There is nothing in the div above the iframe((

For the above screenshots, the element is contained within an iframe. You will not be able to track any interaction with the element as your GTM container doesn't see it.
The only way you would be able to see interactions and track them would be to have access to the embedded URL's GTM container (if there is one) and do the tagging there.
I assume this is a vendor product and you will not have that type of access and I would look to the vendor for any sort of analytics.
There are some instances where you can pass your GA4 ID to the tool and it can push events to your GA4 instance. But this is probably a long shot.
